# Spacing between images in a figure environment

Tags: spacing, graphics, includegraphics

Example :

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image-c}
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image-c}
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image-c}
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image-c}
    % \hspace{20pt}
    \vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, trim={0 0 0 0}, clip]{example-image-a}
  \caption[example]{This is an example}
  \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
```

Which looks as follows:

[image]

The spacing between row with C and row with A is too tight and I would like to be able to add some space here.

Comment: Adding a blank line after `\vspace` should give the spacing you want.

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: `\par  \vspace{0.5cm}` work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a blank line before your `\vspace` command. Remember, a graphic behaves just like a giant letter, so you are looking at a paragraph consisting of such “letters”. With the blank line, the paragraph is broken in two, and the `\vspace` has the intended effect. In general, avoid using `\vspace` in paragraph building mode. Its effect is likely to be confusing.